# Validated JSON producing invalid JSON error in Firebase despite being verified elsewhere and in UTF-8

Tags: json, firebase, import

I have tried all the solutions in other answers to this problem to no avail.

After converting a list of songs to JSON format from cvs I have also validated the JSON (https://codebeautify.org/csv-to-xml-json), I then validated it on https://jsonlint.com/ . I then saved it as UTF-8 and tried importing it to Firebase. After this not being enough, I tried formatting it using https://jsonformatter.org/ . Still, the same error persists: Invalid JSON. Keys cannot be empty or contain '$', '#', '[', ']', '/' or '.'

I have tried removing various characters which don't seem to be providing anything but these have invalidated the JSON completely (according to jsonlint) and it still won't import.

```
I have included the JSON below, if anyone has any ideas what I need to change, please let me know!
```

Thanks!

```js
[
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "id",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "1",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "2",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "3",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "4",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "5",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "6",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "7",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "8",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "9",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "10",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "11",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "12",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "13",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "14",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "15",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "16",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "17",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "18",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "19",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "20",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "21",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "22",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "23",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "24",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "25",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "26",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "27",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "28",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "29",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "30",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "31",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "32",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "33",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "34",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "35",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "36",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "37",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "38",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "39",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "40",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "41",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "42",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "43",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "44",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "45",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "46",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "47",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "48",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "49",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "50",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "51",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "52",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "53",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "54",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "55",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "56",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "57",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "58",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "59",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "60",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "61",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "62",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "63",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "64",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "65",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "66",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "67",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "68",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "69",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "70",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "71",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "72",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "73",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "74",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "75",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "76",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "77",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "78",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "79",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "80",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "81",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "82",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "83",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "84",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "85",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "86",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "87",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "88",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  },
  {
    "NinetyNineSongsAnalysed": "",
    "": ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you remove the empty keys (`""`) it will be fine. See the `Keys cannot be empty or contain '$', '#', '[', ']', '/' or '.'` part of your error message.

Comment: I have removed all of the empty quotation marks (' "" ') but that just makes the error message: invalid JSON appear

Comment: aha, I tried putting a space between the two quotations and that seemed to make a valid json without the empty quotations. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have noting like that at least not in the key , https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OhhXJgNzgr3GRpvjNOOTf2JEqccaAbaU/view?usp=sharing